# Prime factorization program

Tags: erlang

This is my first Erlang program. I need help with my code. I just learned that I can not call functions in guards so I tried to impliment a "case" in my factor/3 helper function. The code compiles, but I get the following error:

*** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  program:factor/3 (program.erl, line 24)
*

```
  -module(program).
  -export([first/1, isProduct/1, factor/1]).


  %returns the first prime factor of the parameter(an integer greater than    1) passed to the function
  first(Num) -> first(Num, 2). 

  %private helper function for first(Num)
  first(Num, Count) when (Num rem Count) == 0 -> Count;
  first(Num, Count) -> Count = Count + 1,
  first(Num, Count).


  %returns the prime factorization of Num as a list of prime numbers
  factor(Num) -> factor(Num, Num, 1, [Rest, first(Num)])

  %helper function for factor(Num)
  factor(Num, StaticNum, Count, [First|Rest]) when Count == StaticNum -> [First, Rest];  
  factor(Num, StaticNum, Count, [First|Rest]) ->
  factor(Num div lists:last([Rest]), StaticNum, (Count * [Rest]), [Rest|first(Num div lists:last([Rest])])).
```

Comment: On your final line you're trying to divide a number by a list: `Num / [Rest]`, which is almost certainly the source of your error since that's not possible. What are you really trying to do there? You need to rethink your approach and change your code. Also, note that you likely want to use `div` rather than `/` because you're trying to do integer division.

Comment: There is an element at the end of the list that I want to divide by. How can I do this.

Comment: `Rest` is the tail of the list so it could well be empty.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed my code so it should work but I need to divide an integer by a number in a list. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: If you're sure the list isn't empty and the number is at the head of the list, you can access it with `hd(List)`. If it's at the end of the list, and again you're sure the list is not empty, you can access it with `lists:last(List)` if you're running Erlang 17.x or newer, or you can get it with `hd(lists:reverse(List))` using any Erlang version.

Comment: @user2355058 , function isProduct always return 0.What algorithm you want to implement?

Comment: i have since made significant changes to my code. My problem is that I want to call the factor/4 function from the factor/1 function where I pass in a list [Rest, first(Num)]. Is this the correct way to insert a number at the tail of a list? I also tried all of Steve's head/tail access methods but they still returned arithmetic errors when I tried to divide.

Comment: @user2355058 , in function factor/1 variable Rest is unbound.

Comment: so I changed it to [first(Num)]. Does this become the Head & Tail?

Comment: @user2355058 Yes,Head = first(Num),Tail = [].In general, I will say as an aspiring novice. Before you write a function in a module, can test the function in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code because the version you wrote cannot compile.

There are many problems here.

```
first(Num, Count) ->
    Count = Count + 1,
    first(Num, Count).
```

Variable are not mutable! You cannot do this, but you can recall first/2 with new parameters:

```
first(Num, Count) ->
    first(Num, Count+1).
```

In addition, this function will never stop if it is called with the parameter 1. You need to add a result for this.

```
%returns the product of factors-in-a-list. 
isProduct([]) -> 0;
isProduct([First|Rest]) -> First * isProduct(Rest).
```

This function always return 0 since it always end with the detection of an empty list. You should write `isProduct([]) -> 1;`

When you find the last factor you insert it in the list with a bad syntax: use `[First|Rest];` not `[First, Rest];`

when you want to iterate, the first parameter is the current remaining Num, so for the next step it should be `Num/Next` with Next = first(Num). Note that in the syntax `[First|Rest]` First is an element (here an integer), while Rest is a list, and you cannot use a list for arithmetic operation.

Last, you want to add a new element to the list of primes, it will be `Next = first(Num)` and you have to put it on top of the list and continue with `Num div Next` (this apply to the first call to factor/3)

your code becomes:

```
-module(program).
  -export([factor/1]).


  %returns the first prime factor of the parameter(an integer greater than    1) passed to the function
  first(1) -> 1;
  first(Num) -> first(Num, 2). 

  %private helper function for first(Num)
  first(Num, Count) when (Num rem Count) == 0 -> Count;
  first(Num, Count) -> first(Num, Count+1).

  %returns the product of factors-in-a-list. 
  isProduct([]) -> 1;
  isProduct([First|Rest]) -> First * isProduct(Rest).



  %returns the prime factorization of Num as a list of prime numbers
  factor(Num) when is_integer(Num), Num > 0 ->
    First = first(Num),
    factor(Num div First, Num,[First]).

  %helper function for factor(Num)
  factor(Num, StaticNum, [First|Rest]) ->
    case isProduct([First|Rest]) == StaticNum of 
      true -> [First|Rest];
      false -> 
          Next = first(Num),
          factor(Num div Next, StaticNum, [Next,First|Rest])
    end.
```

Your version is not optimized since you restart first at 2 every time (important when there are many prime factors) and the stop condition is not optimized (important when there are some "big" prime factors). I would write it this way:

```
decomp(N) when is_integer(N), (N > 0) -> 
    lists:reverse(decomp(N,[],2)).

decomp(N,R,I) when I*I > N -> [N|R];
decomp(N,R,I) when (N rem I) =:= 0 -> decomp(N div I,[I|R],I);
decomp(N,R,2) -> decomp(N,R,3);
decomp(N,R,I) -> decomp(N,R,I+2).
```

Here is the result for the 2 versions measured with timer:tc/3 (on windows 7), the difference of execution time is huge, more than 15000 time faster for this example:

```
2> timer:tc(program,factor,[1234567893200]).
{91349000,[3086419733,5,5,2,2,2,2]}
3> timer:tc(program,decomp,[1234567893200]).
{6000,[2,2,2,2,5,5,3086419733]}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a lot of review/learning to do now that you have both fixed my code and supplied a superior solution. The 15000x faster solution will be fun to dissect, but I am very happy with your modifications to original code and use of isProduct() from the OP(pre edit). I am still frustrated that my knowledge from scheme and racket and erlang doc was not enough for me to fully solve the problem.

Comment: I have a lot of fun using erlang. If you start, don't be discouraged, it takes some time to be used to the not mutable variable and recursion everywhere. But there are plenty of documentation available, and one extremely valuable web site to start learning: [LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content).

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote you code,hope I rightly understand your task.

```
-module(program).
-export([first/1]).

first(Num) when Num >1,is_integer(Num) ->{ok,factor(Num,2)};
first(Num)-> {err,Num}.

factor(Num,Count) when Count>Num+1->[];
factor(Num,Count)->case Num rem Count of
                     0->[Count|factor(Num div Count,Count)];
                     _->factor(Num,Count+1)
                   end.
```